# What part of Voldemort got resurrected?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

We know that Voldemort had a bunch of Horcruxes, plus one soul piece in his body. 
In Book 1, when he "died" the first time (in Godric's Hollow), the rebounding curse destroyed that one soul piece (correct me if I'm wrong). But he "lived" because his Horcruxes still had living soul pieces. 
Fast forward to Book 4. Wormtail made the potion that brought Voldemort back to life. This resurrected Voldemort had a soul piece inside him.

 My question is: which soul piece is this? It can't be the original piece above, nor can it be a piece from a Horcrux. What part got resurrected?

Comment: it was the original piece. After he failed to kill Harry, the cruse rendered him body-less where he used to eventually possess animals (preferably snakes). Then he found Quirrell. once again, his plan failed and was back to square one. Wormtail found this ghostly piece and brought back Voldy

Comment: @Shreedhar Wait, so that piece was alive after the rebounding curse?

Comment: Yeah. let me find the actual quotes. will add it as an answer for you

Comment: *What part of Voldemort got resurrected?* Everything except his nose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It **is** part of the original piece; your premise is flawed in that it is assuming that the soul fragment left inside of Voldemort was destroyed -- it wasn't; a part broke loose from the what remaining portion of soul he had in his body and latched on to Harry, making him a sort of pseudo-horcrux, as Dumbledore confirms to Snape (with the intent that he later tell Harry.)

From The Prince's Tale chapter in Deathly Hallows

> “Tell him that on the night Lord Voldemort tried to kill him, when Lily cast her own life between them as a shield, the Killing Curse rebounded upon Lord Voldemort, and a fragment of Voldemort’s soul was blasted apart from the whole, and latched itself onto the only living soul left in that collapsing building. Part of Lord Voldemort lives inside Harry, and it is that which gives him the power of speech with snakes, and a connection with Lord Voldemort’s mind that he has never understood. And while that fragment of soul, unmissed by Voldemort, remains attached to and protected by Harry, Lord Voldemort cannot die.”

The part that then inhabited animals and eventually Quirell was the remaining portion after the inadvertent split put part into Harry.  The part that didn't go into Harry is what was eventually placed into a new body, allowing him to be effectively resurrected.

Comment: If it helps, remember -- killing a person just frees their soul, but the Horcrux spell works by binding a portion of a soul to an item in the earthly world -- no part of the soul will move on until the entire thing does, so you end up with the disembodied Voldemort possessing animals and Quirell.  But destroying a Horcrux DESTROYS the soul piece inside of it; Voldy was killed, not destroyed, by his rebounding curse. Harry & crew then manage to destroy the Horcruxes, one by one, leaving the last part as the soul in his new body.  That is then killed, not destroyed, hence his fate.

Comment: So what I understand from this is that if a wizard has a Horcrux, his soul (the one still in his body) cannot be destroyed, only broken. Am I right?

Comment: @Righter - More or less; it's never said if there is a way to DESTROY a soul (well, actually, Dementers are said to do that, but that's another issue), but Hermione mentions that when you are killed your soul is not damaged, just released, when she explains how a Horcrux works to Ron & Harry.  The Horcrux is basically a segment of the soul broken off (by a spell plus murder to fragment it and make it possible) that is stored in a physical object.  The 'freed' pieces of a soul won't move on as long as a part is still bound; it wants to reunite before moving on.  And that's possible but painful.

Comment: And a single Horcrux shouldn't render the remaining soul so fragile as to readily break.. But in Voldemort's 'traveling farther down the path to immortality than any other wizard', he broke is SO much that it became fragile and broke when it wasn't meant to.  Normally, killing a wizard just releases their soul, and, if they have a horcrux, it hangs around 'as less than a shade' because it can't move on incomplete.  (It the horcrux is destroyed, there is no remaining part, and it is as 'complete' as it can be, and can move on.  My headcanon is that it wants to reassemble before anything else.)

Comment: Got it; fantastic answer

Answer (score 2):

#### Voldemort’s new body held his ‘old’ soul piece.

The main part of Voldemort’s soul was not actually killed at Godric’s Hollow. It was ripped from his body, rendering him incorporeal, but it was never killed.

> “Voldemort laughed softly in his ear, then took the finger away, and continued addressing the Death Eaters. ‘I miscalculated, my friends, I admit it. My curse was deflected by the woman’s foolish sacrifice, and it rebounded upon me. Aaah … pain beyond pain, my friends; nothing could have prepared me for it. I was ripped from my body, I was less than spirit, less than the meanest ghost … but still, I was alive. What I was, even I do not know … I, who have gone further than anybody along the path that leads to immortality. You know my goal – to conquer death. And now, I was tested, and it appeared that one or more of my experiments had worked … for I had not been killed, though the curse should have done it. Nevertheless, I was as powerless as the weakest creature alive, and without the means to help myself … for I had no body, and every spell which might have helped me required the use of a wand …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 33 (The Death Eaters)*</sup></sub>

After being restored to a body, Voldemort still has clear memory of being ripped from his body in Godric’s Hollow - he remembers casting the Killing Curse at Harry and his Killing Curse rebounding on him, killing his body but not his soul.

> “*He pointed the wand very carefully into the boy’s face: he wanted to see it happen, the destruction of this one, inexplicable danger. The child began to cry: it had seen that he was not James. He did not like it crying, he had never been able to stomach the small ones’ whining in the orphanage –*
>
> ‘Avada Kedavra!’
>
> *And then he broke: he was nothing, nothing but pain and terror, and he must hide himself, not here in the rubble of the ruined house, where the child was trapped and screaming, but far away … far away …”* 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 17 (Bathilda’s Secret)*</sup></sub>

Horcruxes work by tethering the “main” piece of soul to life. Having several Horcruxes simply means that the “main” piece of soul will remain alive until all of Voldemort’s Horcruxes are destroyed and that “main” soul piece is then killed.

> “Well, you split your soul, you see,’ said Slughorn, ‘and hide part of it in an object outside the body. Then, even if one’s body is attacked or destroyed, one cannot die, for part of the soul remains earthbound and undamaged. But, of course, existence in such a form …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 23 (Horcruxes)*</sup></sub>

Voldemort’s “main” piece of soul was ripped from its body, but never killed - the Horcruxes kept it tethered to life, as was their purpose.